# How to count the number of times the spring boot loads on spring tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I've a app with spring boot tests,
can I enforce the number of times that spring boot is loaded?
so if someone will load another spring boot I'll will warn about it.

Comment: The Spring Test Context already caches and reuses loaded contexts, why limit it? If it is loaded either the config is different or you are manually loading it and working around the test context framework. So looks like you are trying to solve the wrong issue.

Comment: To load spring boot in my app takes around 10 sec. I want to save time thus reducing the build time.

Comment: It should be already loaded once!. If that isn't the case you are doing something wrong in your tests OR it is actually needed due to difference in config, test execution listeners, or due to `@DirtiesContext` (to name the most common ones).

Answer (score 6):

*The question is a bit general and my answer may be not exactly what is wanted.*

With
`logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.cache: debug`
you can monitor how many contexts are loaded, for example this project use 7 contexts:

> Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@3655a68c size = 7, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 1780, missCount = 7]